# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: Error message "Failed to execute child process"

Tags: 12.04, launcher

I am an Ubuntu-newbie and just started working with Ubuntu (version 12.04 LTS) a couple of days ago. I wanted to add a launcher icon to desktop for launching an application I previously installed. Up to now I can only launch it by typing

```
setsid matlab -desktop
```

into my terminal.
Now there is the following problem with the execution via the desktop icon:
Whenever I click the desktop icon, I get the following error message:

"Failed to execute child process"
I would like to add a screenshot, but unfortunately as a new user, I am not allowed to...

In the main menu from where I added the icon via drag'n'drop to desktop there is also a permission to execute the .desktop file.

I also tried to look for advice on the error message "Failed to execute child process..." but could not find anything useful.
Now does anybody have an idea what I am missing? Sorry if this is a stupid question ;)
...but as I just said: I just started with Ubuntu...
Thanks to everybody in advance for their help! :)

And let me know if you should need any more information...

Regards, Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Add a desktop launcher following this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop). In the command field enter `matlab -desktop` and choose a name and comment of your liking. You can add it to the launcher simply by dragging and dropping it.

**Edit**: If you installed matlab in your home folder or any other custom directory, replace `matlab -desktop` with `/path/to/matlab -desktop`.

Comment: Hi there,
thanks for the quick response.
I am using 
/home/std/matlab/bin/matlab -desktop
in the command field now since your solution produced a similar error message:
"Details: Failed to execute child process "matlab" (No such file or directory)".
But this was (probably) due to the fact that Ubuntu did not know the path to the executable file. I just stated the complete path and now double-clicking the icon on my desktop works :)
Else, I guess, I would have to add this path to some environment variables etc... which is probably more complicated...

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. I edited my answer to accomodate for different install paths. Please consider accepting my post to help future users with the same or a similar question.

Comment: I would like to rate your post as useful, but unfortunately, I am not allowed to do so. I get a message: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".

Comment: Oh, yes, that's true. New users can't upvote, but you can still click on the small check mark beside an answer to mark it as accepted, if you want.

Comment: @Glutanimate I'm using a dual-boot ubuntu 12.04/windows system and I installed Matlab for ubuntu on media/48xxxxxxxx, i.e. the partition that I understand is my D:/ drive on Windows. Will this solution work for my setting as well? When I right-click the MATLAB executable in the directory that I installed it, and I try to change its permissions by checking the "Allow Execution" check box... it gets unchecked immediately. Should I have installed it somewhere in /home/? Is that the problem?

Comment: @user961627 As far as I know files on Windows partitions (i.e. NTFS/FAT partitions) are set to non-executable by default. You might want to look into finding a way to execute files on NTFS partitions. Please feel free to open a new question if you don't manage to find a solution.